# Android - Placing a Image before the Radio Button

Tags: android

I am creating radio buttons programmatically.
I need to place a image (img1.png / img2.png) in front of some radio buttons dynamically.

Code:

```
myradiobutton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.img1, 0, 0, 0);
```

But the image appears just after the button, and before the text.

```
Who can run faster?
o [img1] Cat
o [img2] Dog
```

But i want it like this(image before radio button):

```
Who can run faster?
[img1] o Cat
[img2] o Dog
```

I have also tried this:

```
myradiobutton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.img1);
```

But this replaces the button itself with the image (don't want that).

```
 [img1]  Cat
 [img2]  Dog
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can wrap up imageView and radiobutton in some layout
or just can create a customview that doest it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas, neither one terribly elegant:

1. Create a horizontal LinearLayout.  In the first cell, put a vertical LinearLayout with the images.  In the second cell, put a RadioGroup with your radio buttons.
2. Create two drawables for each button--one with the circle unfilled and one with the circle filled.  Create a onCheckedChangeListener that will set the drawables according to the checked state.